# Auxiliary-Input Random Oracle Model

Tags: random-oracle-model

Referring to https://eprint.iacr.org/2007/168.pdf, is it true that the auxiliary input random oracle model strengthens the RO model captures the fact that an attacker may know (eg. have hardcoded) a fixed amount of collisions and/or preimages?